# Hash Table Map - updating values

Tags: java, hashtable

I am just using a hash table to remember which complementary colours appear in an image.

Anyway so I get the current value count:

```
Float count = complementaryColour.get(complementaryString[1] + " and " + colourName);
```

and now I want to change count, so I do:

```
count += (Float)((frequency/width*height)*total_distance);
```

and put it back

```
complementaryColour.put(complementaryString[1] + " and " + colourName, count);
```

Yet sadly it doesn't like this! It says I need to create a float count, and then when I look  at the line putting it back in the hashtable it says it cannot be resolved to a variable.

I have seen this done before, but only when we have Integer count... then count++; this can then be returned to the hashtable!

Comment: Can you please give us the whole piece of code where you get the data, update it, and put it back in the map?

Comment: who says? Was he angry? Did you try offering him a beer?

Comment: complementaryString[1] + " and " + colourName - This looks like an incredibly bad idea for a key format

Comment: @ts Yes I know, its not ideal, I just need to keep all the pairs of complementary colours that come up with this single value. Any idea on a better implementation?

Comment: Yes, an object having those pairs of colors as attributes :)

Comment: Who is "it" when you say "It says I need to create a float count"?

Comment: @Vakimshaar thanks! So for an object I assume I need Object[i][3]

Answer (score 0):

As per your question your `Hashtable` is like below.

```
Map <String , Float> complementaryColour=new Hashtable<String, Float >();
```

Try This

```
float f=(float) ((frequency/width*height)*total_distance);
lCount+=f;
```

Comment: If your program is not multithreaded, use ``HashMap`` instead