# Eclipse - Scala IDE and Java SDK

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, ide, eclipse-plugin

So I have Eclipse Indigo running Java and then I wanted to add Scala, which at first was fine.

Now I have gone back into it today and the tab for Scala has gone, along with the option of creating a new Scala project in File - other.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Scala IDE along with the Scala worksheet addin and still it has not returned.

I also have the sbt.exe set up and do have the path environment variable set up.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try cleaning eclipse?    ./eclipse --clean

Comment: do you have the scala perspective open?

Comment: @RC. Hi yes, I did clean it and build it. Also opened and closed Eclipse quite a lot to see if it will open the Scala IDE and still no luck

Comment: @KimStebel  There is no option for Scala, not the proper one anyway, the is a whitened box saying <Scala> but this isn't correct as it does not allow anything else to come up

Comment: @AlexisPigeon I would love to work on it, but some questions do not have an answer nor some do not have appropriate answers!

Comment: It might me helpful to check <workspace>/.metadata/.log. Furthermore, I 'd always be prepared to 'reinstall' eclipse + all its dependencies :-)

Comment: You mentionned yourself this answer worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542250/1065525 . Also, it's quite OK to accept your own answers, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12679717/1065525

Comment: With the information you provide, one can only guess what the issue is. The easiest solution might be to download the Scala IDE from Typesafe: http://typesafe.com/stack/scala_ide_download It bundles everything you need together in one download.

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look at the dev. site issues.

Comment: @KimStebel Thanks- have done so and now working! Added Java projects into typesafe version. Thx